# Eager loading not working - Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, eager-loading

I have eager loaded the data but when I am using $object->attribute it again fetch the data from database.

My query is :

`$user = User::with([
            'Comment' => function($query){
                $query->where('active', 1);
                $query->with('CommentReply.User');
                $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
            }
]);`

But when I use $user->comment then it again load all the comments, which results to N+1 problem. Any reason why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working fine, just stick to one convention:

```
$user = User::with([
            'comment' => function($query){
                $query->where('active', 1);
                $query->with('CommentReply.User');
                $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
            }
]);

//then
$user->comment
```

**or**

```
$user = User::with([
            'Comment' => function($query){
                $query->where('active', 1);
                $query->with('CommentReply.User');
                $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
            }
]);

//then
$user->Comment
```

Notice letter casing.

Also mind that `$comment->commentReply->user` will do just the same, so you need to call `$comment->CommentReply->User`.